# Removing head prolog

Tags: prolog, unification

```
check(Departure, Destination, [(D, S)|T1], [H|T2] ):-
    check(Departure, Destination, T1, T2),
    ((Destination = D, H = D); H = '').
```

I have the above code and I wanted to skip assigning H. I get a list of commas when I do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that the fourth argument always "adds" an item to the list. If you want to "skip" that item altogether can avoid adding `H` to the head of that argument in that case.

i.e.:

```
check(Departure, Destination, [(D, S)|T1], NT2 ):-
    check(Departure, Destination, T1, T2),
    ((Destination = D, NT2=[D|T2]); NT2=T2).
```

The clause states that the fourth argument should have `D` appended to `T2` at the beginning when the recursive call to `check/4` yields the same destination (the left part of the `;` ), thus `NT2=[D|T2]` in that case. Otherwise, the fourth argument should be just what the recursive step leaves in `T2`, thus `NT2=T2` in that case.

Note also that `S` is a singleton in your code. If you really don't want to use S in that procedure then use `_` instead of `S`